# Infinite flat earth weather patterns

Tags: weather

The world is infinite in extent (both in area and age), with no large-scale curvature (normal mountains and such exist). The sun is infinitely far away, but has infinite size. The net effect is to appear with an angular size and brightness equivalent to Earth's sun. Its daily path across the sky is roughly what would be seen from Australia: rises in the East, Northward at noon, sets in the West, solar elevation angle changes throughout the year just as on Earth. So on average each unit area of the world's surface receives the same amount of energy as does the Earth's surface around 25 degrees latitude. The seasons (caused by the yearly cycle of solar angle) are simultaneous over the whole world (ie every location has summer at the same time). I have considered having seasons vary by position but haven't come up with an interesting scheme so far.

Under the surface is rock to a great depth. There might be an "undersurface" if you go down far enough, but it's probably tens of thousands of kilometers down if it exists. There are no plate tectonics, but there are creatures of truly enormous size whose burrowings (very) occasionally create mountains.

Ocean salinity is the same as Earth's in amount and general distribution. In the absence of plate tectonics, this is maintained by some process that I haven't yet determined.

At night, the sky is black with many stars, and from most places on the surface there are one or perhaps a few moons visible. The moons are mountain-sized floating rocks that shine independently of the sun. There are no gravitationally significant objects in this universe other than the world itself.

With no Coriolis force and a simultaneous day/night cycle and solar elevation angle across the entire surface, there would be no circulation cells (Hadley, Ferrel, Polar) like Earth has, thus no prevailing westerlies or easterly trade winds.

The question is this: are there any effects that would cause larger weather patterns than the mesoscale?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107978/discussion-on-question-by-octa9on-infinite-flat-earth-weather-patterns).

Answer (score 1):

Geography.

If you have large oceans and large mountain ranges, they will have much larger effects, through their effects on rainfall.  The places near the sources of evaporation will get more rain, and the mountains will get far more rain on the side facing the body of water than the other, which will be part of the rainshadow.

Also, the farther inland you go, the more temperature will vary, both up and down.  Water has so high a specific heat that it moderates the temperature need it.

Comment: Would there be geographic effects above the mesoscale / at the cyclonic scale?

Comment: They can.  The rainshadow of the Rocky Mountains affects the entirety of the Great Plains.  You could go either way.  The larger the bodies of water and the stretches of land, and the greater the height and length of the mountains, the greater the effect, but a more intermixed pattern with lower mountains will minimize them.

Comment: The world has at least as large mountains (Himalayas) and oceans (Pacific) as Earth, though since it's infinite in extent, it could easily have much larger of both. Would the Rocky Mountains have such a large rainshadow without the prevailing westerlies of the Ferrel cell?